# Is it possible to change SettingsAPI Dialog box's text color?

Tags: android, android-dialog, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

[image]

I followed this to get the above pop up-
[link to the code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationSettings/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationsettings/MainActivity.java)

Is there a way to change the text color of Learn more, CANCEL and TURN ON text fields?

Something like this-
[image]

Comment: I think its your theme color.

Comment: Did you prompted that dialog inside your app? How did you do that?

Comment: @BenjaminFell First pic i called from one of Activity, 2nd pic is the client's requirement...

Comment: @PratikButani : Its the default android dialog box , any idea of how to change it? Even google maps shows greenish blue color text.

Comment: Could you please provide the code you used to prompt that dialog?

Comment: @BenjaminFell updated the post